# Can I create a Chrome Extension that save images to specific names?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I like to save images to my hard-drive to create mood-board for art projects. I usually use Date.now() in chrome's console to create a string of number and copy the number as my file name - so the saved images are in the an order - it is easier for me to look them up later.

I thought, it would be convenient if I create an extension to help me to accomplish this.

So I want to create a new option in the context menu and call it "Download This Image" and when I click it, it will automatically generate a string of number and use them as the default file name. Unfortunately, it doesn't quite work out.

The reason I want to create a new option is that, most of the time, I don't want to change the filename of the images I download. I only want to change them when I want to save them to my inspirational folder.

Comment: Also, there is a new challenge, you should check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727109/how-to-remember-last-download-location-when-calling-chrome-downloads-download

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I solved this. Here is the extension's source code if anyone is interested.

https://github.com/aeroxy/save_image