# How to remember last download location when calling chrome.downloads.download? (Extension Developer)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

The default behavior for [chrome.downloads.download](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download) is to download to the default download folder. It doesn't remember it if you change the folder. Can we save the download-to location for the next call-out?

References: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's concerning that Chrome actually doesn't provide the ability for an extension to get the last download path. Some say, it's due to security concern and others say, there is no significant need to have the API available to users.

You also cannot store the download path in your extension because Chrome doesn't let you get the selected download folder. I hope Google provides us with the either of these features later.

Comment: Do you have any references you can share? (eg: a feature request where it's acknowledged that this doesn't exist, or a bug report)

Answer (score 5):

This is not a supported feature, according to [this Chromium discussion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=838952&q=chrome.downloads.download&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).

Summary:

1. If you specify a filename, it's *never* possible to save outside of ~/Downloads (this is a bummer, for me)
2. You should be able to manually implement something (in a subfolder only) using the id returned from `Chrome.downloads.download`

A few quotes I like (edited for brevity and politeness):

> Would like a download option to choose recent download folder. Would be good to remember last download location per website, like you other settings.

Seems reasonable.

> Chrome does remember the last chosen directory if no filename is specified to downloads.download with Save As... Given how Save As works without specifying a filename, my intuition would be it would work the same with a filename... but it doesn't.

That one is interesting. So it kind of supports it already. There's no security concern with saving outside of Downloads.

Comment: I can confirm that using `saveAs: true` but not `filename:` does allow the download folder to be remembered.

Answer (score 4):

I have just been able to restore the "remember last download location" functionality, which used to work on my previous machine, in a new install by disabling extensions and Chrome apps *provided by Google*. This is what I have turned off:

- Extension: Google Docs Offline
- Chrome Apps: Docs, Sheets, Slides

I haven't tried to narrow down which of these have been the culprit, or if any other extensions (I have a bunch) have played a role. So YMMV. Good luck :)

Comment: In my case it was the "Image Downloader - Bulk download images" extension which prevented remembering the last download location.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. Very simple way: Insert a USB-drive or SD-card. Go to chrome settings, and specify this drive as the default download location.
Remove the drive/SD-card. Download something - the first time you do it, Chrome will offer to save to your user document folder, but instead, you save it to whereever you want.
This location will be remembered next time. Voila. So easy.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, you can save previous the download location.

If you do a clean install, first of everything, change the download settings to "ask every time". It is very important not to click the text box where you can specify one download location (if you click there just once, you need a clean install again).

Chrome will then bring up the download window with your last save location.

Furthermore, you should uncheck the "settings" in the sync preferences because it will break every time you sync your settings to a new browser.